# aws s3 mv command is impacting the performance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

We are implementing a near real-time project where we get the raw data into S3 folder. We receive almost 2000 files for every 5 mins.

As part of the requirement, we have to move/archive the files from S3 to another folder in S3. We have to move only those files which are older than 10 mins. Currently using the below script which we are scheduling for every 5 mins. But sometimes it takes more than 5 mins to run.

Is there anyway that we can improve the performance by using any other feature like s3cmd?

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script archives the files in S3 folder older than 10mins And is scheduled for every 5 mins

dt=`date +"%Y%m%d"`
s3_input=s3://bucket/input/
s3_archive=s3://bucket/archive/$dt/
olderThan=`date --date "10 minutes ago" +%s`
s3files=""

#loop for all the files in the input path
aws s3 ls $s3_input| grep "<string starts with>" |( while read -r line;
do
  #Get creation date and timestamp of the S3 file
  createDate=`echo $line | awk {'print $1" "$2'}`
  createDate=`date -d "$createDate" +%s`

  if [[ $createDate -lt $olderThan ]]; then
     fileName=`echo $line | awk {'print $4'}`
     #s3files="$s3files --include $fileName"
     aws s3 mv $s3_input$fileName $s3_archive$fileName
  fi
done

#if [[ ! -z $s3files ]]; then
   #aws s3 mv $s3_input $s3_archive --recursive --exclude "*" ${s3files}
#fi
)
```

Thanks

Comment: One way would be to do it in batches of files in parallel. For instance, instead of doing it one by one, you would have to modify the script to move. e.g. 5, files at the same time in one iteration of your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know all the parameters of your task, but I would suggest this scheme:

1. Create SQS queue with 10 mins of visibility delay for messages
2. Subscribe SQS to S3 bucket events, so every object creation event creates message in SQS
3. Subscribe Lambda function to this queue, write code to move the object to your archive location

This is more easily manageable and you don't need a lot of infrastructure to support, since lambda is serverless.

Comment: Just to add one more important detail here. I think the SQS queue should be a FIFO queue.

Comment: @jellycsc depends on how important the order of archiving is, but as an option it should definitely be considered